# Form MDI child no se ajusta correctamente al Form parent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, interfaz-gráfica

Buen día colegas, tengo un problemilla con los MDI Form en un proyecto de Visual Basic.NET (Visual Studio 2013): estoy intentando crear un programa para guardar contactos tipo agenda con una interfaz moderna pero estoy teniendo problemas con los MDI Form que uso, como pueden ver en la imagen al abrir un Form MDI child no se ajusta correctamente al Form parent.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo corregir eso? Al abrir el programa se ve bien porque le puse bien el tamaño pero después de abrir otros forms se descuadran todos. Al ocultarse y volver a aparecer (cualquier Forma MDI child) sale como está en la foto...

Agradecería su ayuda colegas con este tema. Gracias

Comment: Creo que aquí es importante que incluyas el código que define cada contenedor. Pues, para que puedan darte respuestas relevantes a tu problema en vez de adivinar o dar respuestas muy amplias

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Ah okay... Tienes razón lamento los inconvenientes, seré más específico para la próxima.

Answer (score 0):

Para corregir esos desajustes tienes que entender bien las mecánicas de los contenedores y jugar con las propiedades `Anchor` o `Dock`, a parte de sus medidas.

En el caso que nos muestras ahora mismo, sería tan simple como por ejemplo, ponerle al contenedor del menú la propiedad `Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left` o la propiedad `Dock = Left`.

Las diferencias entre estas 2 propiedades son las siguientes:

**[Anchor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=netcore-3.1):** Esta propiedad te permite ancorar el control donde le estés indicando, pero no te lo movería de la `Location` donde lo hayas puesto, simplemente lo redimensionaría dependiendo de lo grande o pequeña que se haga la pantalla.

Ejemplo con `Anchor = Top, Left, Right`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso siempre te redimensionará el control hacia arriba, derecha e izquierda siempre respetando los espacios que tu le has dejado.

**[Dock](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netcore-3.1):** Esta propiedad lo que hace es mover el control entero a la posición donde le estés marcando, pero te va a limitar la redimensión, por ejemplo, si le dices `Dock = Left` te colocará el control a la izquierda del contenedor ocupando des de la parte superior del control padre hasta la inferior y solo podrías redimensionar hacia la derecha.

Ejemplo con `Dock = Left`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]